# SetWindowPlacement function does not setting the console window size properly

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to set the placement of given windows. **Currently, my program works with most applications (e.g., Chrome, Notepad), but has some unexpected results with console windows**. When calling the function SetWindowPlacement on a console window, there seem to be some extra offsets added to the coordinate I gave as input. I wonder if this has something to do with some special window style of the console window.

I've tried to use both "rcWork" (workspace coordinate) and "rcMonitor" (monitor coordinate), and both have this extra offsets.

```
// Get this console window's hWnd (window handle).
IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();

// Get information about the monitor (display) that the window is (mostly) displayed on.
// The .rcWork field contains the monitor's work area, i.e., the usable space excluding
var mi = MONITORINFO.Default;
GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), ref mi);

// Get information about this window's current placement.
var wp = WINDOWPLACEMENT.Default;
GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref wp);

// Calculate the window's new position: snap right 
wp.NormalPosition = new RECT()
    {
        Left = mi.rcWork.Left + (mi.rcWork.Right - mi.rcWork.Left) / 2,          
        Top = mi.rcWork.Top,
        Right = mi.rcWork.Right,
        Bottom = mi.rcWork.Bottom
    };

// Place the window at the new position.
SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref wp);
```

The window is supposed to occupy the entire right half of the screen, but there is actually some offset on the edge. When manipulating other types of windows, the code works as expected. This only happens with console windows.